# TFS: How can I stop untested code from getting on the beta and live servers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, tfs

I have two developers that work in separate sections of code. We use TFS and visualstudio.com to manage our code in one place. After they check in their code, and I Get Latest Version, it pulls in all their changes to my desktop. Then I publish from my desktop to the beta server, do some tests then publish to the live server.

I often get bugs on live system because someone has checked in code that I didn't know about and hadn't tested myself. They may pass a unit test but they may be bad like exposing private data to other users. So I want some way to tick things off as having been approved, before things sneak on to the beta or live servers. How do I do it? I can not see any approval process for this in visual studio. All options I have are Check In, Get Latest Version, and that's really all I can see to use. What else can I do to improve things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.  Are you using TFSVC or Git with TFS?

For starters, when use TFS to build your code, it will show the change sets that have changed since the last build.  You can also tie this to work items, so you can provide more context to them by tying changesets to work items.

Another option, if using Git, is to enable Pull Requests.  Then you can review each pull request by the developers, and approve the merges yourself.

There are also code review options (although these are being largely supplanted by pull requests).

Finally, you can simply deny those users the ability to checkin code to your master branch, and do the checkins yourself.

Most of these options require YOU to take a more active role in reviewing changes.  But, if you want control over what goes into the code, that is probably necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to create branches like deploy, develop etc. Keep checking in in your develop branch unless you think it is ready to go to live site, when ready merge the develop to deploy, that's what I do anyway. Hope it helps.